# Centering div's child element

Tags: html, css, jsfiddle

I have the following [js-fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wy7rd/). It's basically just a `div` that has a bunch of square child elements. The issue is that the `div` doesn't always stay centered. I've already set the following `CSS`:

```
.boutique-grid {
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

I am not sure why it's not centering the child element div's. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove float left from your .boutique-grid-column class. It will solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The `boutique-grid` is centered, but it's 100% wide. You can set a width to for example, 710px;

```
.boutique-grid {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 710px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set width of `div` and `image`.

```
.boutique-grid {
    width: 300px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: Not always will this help. Because 'width' would not be static each and every time. Solution by Ganesh is correct, removing 'float:left' would surely make this work.

Answer (score 0):

```
.boutique-grid {
    text-align: center;    
}

.boutique-grid-column {
    ...
    margin: 0 auto;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `float:left;` and this will work fine, you already have `display:inline-block;` set so no need to float the element.

http://jsfiddle.net/wy7rd/3/

Answer (score 0):

This is what [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-float) says about `float`:

> The element generates a block box that is floated to the left. Content flows on the right side of the box, starting at the top (subject to the 'clear' property).

This is why `.boutique-grid-column` becomes block when `float` is specified and ignores `text-align`.